# Angular, d3.js, test inner functions with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, jasmine

I have some functions that I want to be isolated within directives/services, etc., that directives/services use, but which
I do not need to have access from outside of these directives/services. For example:

```
angular.module('result')
.factory('directiveCreationService', ['$http', dirService]);

function dirService($http){
     function helperFunc1(){...};
     function helperFunc2(){...};
  return {
         // Both functions use helperFunc1, helperFunc2
            usefulFunc1: function($http){...};
            usefulFunc2: function($http){...};
  };
};
```

I want to test helperFunc1 and helperFunc2 in isolation. To test usefulFunc1 and usefulFunc2 is easy: I am just accessing them directly in my tests after injecting the service, but is there
a way to test
helperFunc1, helperFunc2 without making them accessible to the outside world
(I do not want them to, I want them to remain private except for tests)?
I am using Jasmine. So, is it possible in Jasmine to somehow call these
inner functions?

I am also interested in testing a part of a function, so is there a way to access a variable (that is in itself a function) inside a function and do the testing without actually creating another function for the variable and returning it? For example, I have a long function:

```
 longFunc(){
    // some d3.js code
    var1 = svg1.smth.smth.smth.....
    var2 = svg2.smth.smth.smth.....
}
```

I want to get var1 and var2 in my Jasmine tests without actually exposing them. Obviously, I need these var1, var2 for my longFunc to work, but do not need them to expose them in my code because no other external code ever needs them.

Is there any npm modules that can allow Jasmine to do this? Any suggestions?

Comment: In cases like this I remember to [test the interface, not the implementation](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/test-the-interface-not-the-implementation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No unfortunately you can't because they're scoped within the other function. There's no way for you to reference those functions in your code and Jasmine can't do anything magic to allow you to do this. This leaves you with 2 options:

1. Don't unit test them. As @Sonata suggested you should just test the interface (essentially black box testing). Put some input in, and check the output is correct.
2. Change your architecture such that they're no longer privately scoped and you will then be able to test them. Generally I don't advocate this approach unless you have a complex function that you really want to push through unit testing. This sort of reason is why some people argue against things like TDD because you've now got to architect for your tests, rather than the primary purpose of the software.